# Автоскрол вниз при получении или отправке сообщения?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

поставил при нажатии кнопки отправить метод scroll

```js
scroll() {
document.getElementById('textmessage').scrollTop = document.getElementById('textmessage').scrollHeight;
}
```

при нажатии на кнопку отправить ползунок опускается вниз, но не прокручивается до последнего сообщения.
[image: действие при нажатии на кнопку]

[весь код компонента](https://yadi.sk/d/1QcvTQdxpkQ6dA)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете прописать

```
document.getElementById('textmessage').scrollTop = 
document.getElementById('textmessage').scrollHeight;
```

И добавить к `document.getElementById('textmessage').scrollHeight` высоту блока с сообщением, если у вас не проходит скролл до последнего сообщения.

Я так понимаю вы сначала отправляете сообщение, а затем прокручиваете ленту вниз. Попробуйте сделать это Асинхронно, потому что при отправке сообщения, из-за синхронизации кода, может уже пройти прокрутка, и новое сообщение просто добавится ниже, а прокрутка останется на том же месте.

Comment: Спасибо! теперь работает как надо при отправке сообщения! осталась только при входящем сообщении прокручиваться вниз и при старте установить начальную позицию скрола в самом низу